# Mutt retrieve without duplicates or deleting everything

Tags: mutt

I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> keybinding to retrieve mail from my POP mail server. Whenever I do this, Mutt will ask me if I want to delete messages from the server.

If I tell it "no", it will download all of the messages from the server over again, resulting in duplicate messages in my inbox.

If I tell it "yes", it deletes everything from the server.

I need to be able to access my emails on different devices, but I don't want to go through the hassle of downloading every single email over and over again whenever I check my email. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

This answer provides a way to remove/delete duplicate emails in mutt email client. At present I myself still am unaware how to prevent the duplicate email download in the first place. Anyway this is how to at least remove the clutter:

Since the sequence of commands might be not straight-forward, here a recipe list:

1. Set mutt to display/sort messages according to thread: press <kbd>o</kbd> and then select <kbd>t</kbd> for thread.
2. Once in thread mode you can *tag*(=select/mark) the dupplicate copies of messages via: <kbd>T</kbd> and then inputing the pattern `~=`. As a result all duplicate copies should have a `*` for displaying
   them as currently *tagged*
3. Now input `;d` to mark the duplicates messages deleted. Depending
   on you configuration the messages will be presented with a `D` (for deleted) in front  of them, or even be gone directly

If set deleted to (`D` flag); you still need to purge the messages from the
maildir. This purging of the `D` marked messages can be achieved hitting <kbd>$</kbd> which saves the changes to the maildir file/folder. It will ask you to confirm the deletion of the messages.

Comment: “~=“ saved my day. I was trying to do the same with Lua scripting